# Qt ENUMS - setProperty implicit cast

Tags: qt, properties, enums, metaclass

Consider the following class:

```
class foo : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT 
  Q_ENUMS(E)
  Q_PROPERTY(E x READ x WRITE setx)

  public:
    enum E {
      a = 0,
      b = 1,
      c = 2
    };
}

foo f; 
f->setProperty("x", 2);
```

does not provide the mapped enum value to setx.

Is there a way to enable this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need the actual get and set methods:

```
class Foo : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_ENUMS(E)
  Q_PROPERTY(E x READ x WRITE set_x)

  public:
    enum E {
      a = 0,
      b = 1,
      c = 2
    };

    E x() const { return x_; }
    void set_x(E value) { x_ = value; }

private:
    E x_;
};
```

This will now work:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

  Foo f;

  f.setProperty("x", Foo::c);
  std::cout << f.property("x").toInt() << std::endl;  // 2

  f.setProperty("x", 0);  // Foo:a will also work
  std::cout << f.property("x").toInt() << std::endl; // 0
}
```

Comment: I'm closing this question and reopening it with a lot more details (I am fully aware how to write accessors, but I guess we needed a simpler example to play with and understand the issues): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609894/qt-q-enum-property-from-qvariantqulonglong